# In the below once job triggers it will take instance details then it will call outbound API but its failing when it calls out api

Tags: pkcs#12

logger":"c.m.i.t.application.util.ServiceUtil","message":" service util exception : {}","stack_trace":"java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length\n\tat java.base/sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.init(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)\n\tat ;biz ops updated nifi certs but not related to my service but still throwing above error

How to fix this error; is that error related to some certs which needs to be upated?